# Relation between different forms of Cauchy-Kovalevskaya Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following form of Cauchy-Kovalevskaya (CK) theorem for a system of PDE:

> For a given system of PDE with $p$ unknown functions $u^{(1)}, \dots,
>  u^{(p)}$ and variables $x, y_1, \dots, y_n$ of the form 
>   $$
>  u^{(1)}_x=G_1(u^{(1)}, \dots, u^{(p)}, u^{(1)}_{y_1}, \dots,
>  u^{(p)}_{y_1}\dots,u^{(1)}_{y_n}, \dots, u^{(p)}_{y_n})\\ \vdots\\
>  u^{(p)}_x=G_p(u^{(1)}, \dots, u^{(p)}, u^{(1)}_{y_1}, \dots,
>  u^{(p)}_{y_1}\dots,u^{(1)}_{y_n}, \dots, u^{(p)}_{y_n}) $$ 
>   subject to
>    initial conditions $$u^{(1)}(0, \mathbf{y})=g_1(\mathbf{y})\\ \vdots\\
> u^{(p)}(0, \mathbf{y})=g_p(\mathbf{y})$$
>   suppose that $g_1, \dots, g_p$ are holomorphic in a neighborhood of the point $\mathbf{y}^0$ and $G_1, \dots, G_p$ are holomorphic in a neighborhood of the value of their arguments evaluated at $(0, \mathbf{y}^0)$. Then there exists a neighborhood of $(0, \mathbf{y}^0)$ where the system above has a holomorphic solution satisfying the initial conditions.

Taking this theorem for granted, I want to use it to prove another version of CK theorem for a single PDE of order $m$ in the variables $x, \mathbf{y}$ of the form
$$D^m_xu=F(x, \mathbf{y}, u, D_x^kD_y^{\alpha}u \text{ with } k<m \text{ and } k+|\alpha|\le m)$$
satisfying the initial conditions
$$D^i_xu(0, \mathbf{y})=f_i(\mathbf{y})$$
for $0\le i<m$.

I am familiar with the idea of associating a system of first order equations to a single $m$th order PDE with initial values, however I suspect that in that process the functions $G_i$ in the system will also depend on the variables $x, \mathbf{y}$ just as $F$ does, so the above form of CK theorem is not immediately applicable. Does anyone know a way around this issue?

As another question, does the statement of CK above remain valid if $G_i$ depend on the variables $x, \mathbf{y}$? (For instance, when the equations have non-constant coefficients). [Edit: The answer to this question is affirmative. See my 2nd comment below.]

Any thoughts on this are welcome.

Comment: There's in fact a very simple thing you can do. Artificially add to your list of unknowns the coordinate functions $x,y$. $x$ solve $\partial_x x = 1$ and $y$ solves $\partial_x y = 0$, both are first order PDEs.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you very much! You can make your comment an answer so that I can accept it if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converted and expanded from a comment.)

You can artificially add to your list of unknowns the coordinate functions $x$ and $\mathbf{y}$. They solve first order PDEs of the form 
$$ \partial_x x = 1 $$
and
$$ \partial_x \mathbf{y} = 0.$$

So starting with a system $\mathbf{v}$ that solves
$$ \partial_x \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{g}(x,\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{v}, \partial_\mathbf{y} \mathbf{v}) $$
the enlarged system $\mathbf{V} = (x,\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{v})$ now solves a system of the form 
$$ \partial_x \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{V}, \partial_{\mathbf{y}} \mathbf{V}) $$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

I *do not* think you can apply the first theorem to the second statement you want to prove, because there is an essential difficulty: The first theorem only applies to *holomorphic functions*. The classical Cauchy-Kovalevskaya Theorem also need to assume the functions are *analytic*. Otherwise I think there are counter-examples.

For a correct statement of the theorem and the proof, check the corresponding proof in Evans or Tao's book *nonlinear dispersive equations, Chapter 1*, where this is given as a homework execrise with some hints. There are also plenty of proofs online. The proof (I did at least) is very technical and you need a careful control of the terms involved. The confusion you have should evaporate once you boil down to the base case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am assuming holomorphicity of $f_i$ and $F$ for the $m$th order equation just as in the first form of CK theorem. Indeed, analyticity is not my concern at all. I just don't see how to handle the (potential) dependence on $x, \mathbf{y}$ of the functions $G_i$, obtained from forming a system of PDE equivalent to the given $m$th order equation. BTW these forms of CK are discussed in Knapp's advanced analysis and there it is claimed that the first form implies the second...

Comment: I just checked Folland's PDE book and he (on page 48) includes the possibility of the dependence of $G_i$ on $x, \mathbf{y}$ in the statement of CK theorem.